# how to create readonly account in centos?

Tags: centos

I want to create an account with readonly permission on centos7 Even after googling, there is no way to create an account with readonly permission. I wonder how to create an account with no write permission to file and only read permission.

Comment: Where this r/o permission should apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is not clear; accounts in Linux are not read-only.

I assume you are asking about one of the following instead:

1. Creating an account which cannot be logged into
2. Creating an account which *can* be logged into but where other users cannot modify files under that user's home directory
3. Creating an account which *can* be logged into but where the user is restricted from writing to some other folder.

### 1. Creating an account which cannot be logged into

This can be done by setting the user's shell to `/bin/false`. This is generally used for things like creating a system account to run processes under but which is not available to use for logging in. By default, a home folder will still be added for such a user, despite being unpractical in most cases, unless you also specify `--no-create-home`. I also like to set the `--inactive 0` option which "disables the account as soon as the password has expired".

```
sudo useradd --system --no-create-home --inactive 0 --shell /bin/false NAME_OF_USER
```

To use the account, generally you still need to set a password. This alone does not allow logging into a shell but *does* allow the account to be used for local authentication and for you to use the account for running processes etc.

To set a password on the new account (from your normal amount or from the `root` account):

```
sudo passwd NAME_OF_USER
```

### 2. Creating an account which *can* be logged into but where other users cannot modify files under that user's home directory

The user's home folder should be created such that the user is the owner and they have rwx permissions for the folder; otherwise, the user would be unable to login correctly even after they set a password. If I recall correctly, graphical sessions would not be possible in this situation but I think logging in from terminal would be possible, it would just generate an error and temporarily (for that session) change the user home to a temporary location (at least, this is what I remember happening from a misconfiguration I had several years ago).

You can change the permissions for folders that you are the owner of. So, if you wanted to prevent "other" users from being able to modify your files but still allow reading, you could use:

```
chmod -R o-w ~
```

The `-R` option indicates that the change should be applied recursively to all subfolders and files. The `o-w` indicates that we want to *remove* the **w**rite permission for **o**ther users. Finally, `~` is shorthand for your own home folder's location.

I actually recommended preventing read access to most subfolders under your home folder, especially hidden "dot" folders such as `~/.mozilla` as otherwise a user could make a complete copy of the subfolder, including any stored passwords.

To disable all access for other users under your home folder:

```
chmod -R o-wrx ~
```

This is basically the same command as before except that in addition to the write permission, we're also removing the **r**ead and e**x**ecute permissions for other users as well.

Finally, you can set a "umask" value in your `~/.bashrc` file to define the starting permissions for any new files or folders created by your user (this applies mostly for files created in the terminal... graphical applications like file managers might not honor your umask settings).

```
# new dirs => 770
# new files => 660
umask 0007
```

Since this is already a long answer and umask is somewhat complex, I will not go into that in depth here. You can find more info on umasks here: https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/rhce-study-guide/how-to-change-default-umask-permission-in-linux.html

### 3. Creating an account which *can* be logged into but where the user is restricted from writing to some other folder.

If you don't want another user such as a guest account able to access some folder, you just have to change the permissions similar to under the 2nd section but from a different account.

E.g. if you have user "main" and user "guest" and you don't want guest to be able to write to the folder "/media/shared-stuff" which is owned by user main.

First, login as "main" then

```
chmod -R o-w /media/shared-stuff
```

This also assumes that you have not changed the group for the folder to a group that both of these users belong to. By default, the group should be the same as your user name and you will be the only person in that group. But if you used `chown` or `chgrp` to change which group is considered the owner and user "guest" is part of that group, then you would need to do the following to prevent him from being able to write:

chmod -R g-w /media/shared-stuff

This is basically the same as before, but rather than removing the write permission for **o**ther users, we're removing it from the **g**roup